# Samsung Opensource: Compiled kernel size is bigger than stock kernel

Tags: android, android-kernel

I am trying to update kernel for my SM-A500S using device source code at http://opensource.samsung.com. I have done the following steps to get the zImage file:

1. Extract the Kernel.tar.gz to kernel folder
2. Install eabi-4.7 tool chains and lz4c library
3. Change nothing and execute build_kernel.sh

The build process is success and I can find the zImage file at "kernel/arch/arm/boot/" but the size for my kernel is too big (18.09 MB) comparing with the stock kernel size (8.50 MB). I have tried to create the new boot image by doing the following steps:

1. Extract stock boot.img using abootimg
2. Edit bootimg.cfg and remove the bootsize number
3. Create new boot image with abootimg --create

and tried to update the kernel using Odin v3.07.

Odin v3.07 return error with FAIL (Size).

What I have done wrong so far ?? How can I reduce my kernel size to the same as stock roms ??

Thank you so much